# Codec Issue with OpenSuse (Tumbleweed)

Tags: opensuse, vlc, codec

I just installed OpenSuse for the first time in my life. I am trying to run some videos on it. But VLC throws an error

```
VLC could not decode the format "h264" (H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10))
```

I tried searching for some solutions but could not find any concrete solutions for it. I tried making an account on the Suse forums, but somehow cant get my new account to work. So I am asking it here. I have all the codec packs installed I think.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install multimedia codecs. You can get them from Packman Essentials repository :

```
zypper ar -cfp 90 http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/\
openSUSE_Tumbleweed/Essentials packman-essentials
zypper dup --from packman-essentials --allow-vendor-change
sudo zypper install --from packman-essentials ffmpeg gstreamer-plugins-{good,bad,ugly,libav} libavcodec-full vlc-codecs
```

More information on https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Tumbleweed and https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Installing_codecs_from_Packman_repositories

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes VLC fails to load already installed codecs. Then you have to start VLC in verbose move and check what stops VLC from loading codecs

```bsh
$ vlc -vvvv
...
[000055e59a4d1a30] main libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/access/libavio_plugin.so' (libvulkan.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[000055e59a4d1a30] main libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/codec/libavcodec_plugin.so' (libvulkan.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[000055e59a4d1a30] main libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/demux/libavformat_plugin.so' (libvulkan.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[000055e59a4d1a30] main libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/packetizer/libpacketizer_avparser_plugin.so' (libvulkan.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[000055e59a4d1a30] main libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/stream_out/libstream_out_chromaprint_plugin.so' (libvulkan.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[000055e59a4d1a30] main libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/video_chroma/libswscale_plugin.so' (libvulkan.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[000055e59a4d1a30] main libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/video_filter/libpostproc_plugin.so' (libvulkan.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[000055e59a4d1a30] main libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/video_output/libgl_plugin.so' (libvulkan.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[000055e59a4d1a30] main libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib64/vlc/plugins/vdpau/libvdpau_avcodec_plugin.so' (libvulkan.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
...
```

In my case `libvulkan` was missing so I installed it with `sudo zypper in libvulkan1`